# Raid rebuild and resize after replacing larger disk

Tags: raid

I have a Raid 1 with 250 and 500 GB disks on 3ware 9650SE-2LP Windows Server 2008 and I have right now only 500 GB disks to replace temporarily the failed 250 GB drive.

I understand that the Controller will not resize from 250 to 500 GB after the Raid rebuild, but I doubt if I can later go back to the old Raid configuration of 2x 250 GB disks.

I would be glad of your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call 3ware to confirm this (so far all my call to them have been clearly answered and quite to the point), but if you replace the failed drive with the new larger drive you should get a working array.  One with 250GB space. Even if you replace all drives with larger ones.

If you want to use the additional space then you might want to make a backup, test the backup, change drives and recreate the array using the full size of the drives. (And ofcourse restore the backup).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Hennes! Just called the awesome LSI support team and they confirm, I will be able to replace later the 500 GB disks with the original 250s if I don't resize the array. I don't need the 500 space right now, that's why I want to go back to 250.